# Eclipse org migration

Tags: ide, migration

I am trying to migrate meta data from two non related orgs via eclipse
I have doubts in below

1. I remember we were able to select only required fields when we import meta data from source environment which doesn't seem to be there anymore. Now if I have to deploy only certain fields to destination-how do I do? Am I missing something?
2. Can I migrate record types via Eclipse. If not what is the alternative? (Migration tool?)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deploy only a subset of the metadata from one org into another org, I'd recommend the trying this approach.

1. In the source org, go to Setup -> Create -> Packages and create an unmanaged package for the metadata you want to migrate.
2. Click the Add button and select the metadata you want to include.  Any dependencies of the metadata you add will also automatically be included.
3. In Eclipse, start a new workspace pointed at the source org.  Select the unmanaged package from Step 1 as the source rather than selecting metadata types to retrieve
4. Retrieve from server

What you'll get is a directory of metadata which when deployed will create the same unmanaged package in the target org, deploy all the metadata you wanted to migrate, and then add it to the unmanaged package in the target org.  This is also handy because the metadata you imported into the target org is effectively grouped under the unmanaged package.

The key to this is that the package.xml you get from the source org when doing a retrieve from the package has the `<fullName>` element in it and explicitly lists all metadata from the package.  This allows you to essentially recreate the package in another org via the Metadata API.

Another option is to use the force cli (https://github.com/heroku/force) which can retrieve from a package.